# How does Exchange on Android work?

Tags: android, push, exchange-server, android-c2dm, power-management

Not really a programming question, but I'm currently researching battery life and PUSH notifications on Android for an assignment.

I'm aware that third-party apps are able to use C2DM to be able to respond to PUSH notifications even while the phone is sleeping.

Besides responding to an SMS, is there any other way for third-party apps to listen for PUSH notifications without running as a service and keeping the phone awake?

How does the built in Exchange e-mail in ICS work? It seems that the phone is able to sleep even with an Exchange account set to use PUSH. Does this mean that the exchange service goes through Google's C2DM framework, or is it implemented in some other way? E.g. the phone has an idle connection directly with the given Exchange server but is still somehow able to sleep between incoming packets?